# AWS AMP : 502 Bad Gateway: unable to proxy request - WebIdentityErr: failed to retrieve credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

i have eks setup and provisioned aws managed service for prometheus. Created policy with AMP full access( "aps:*") and attached that policy to role which is used by EKS.

Prometheus is installed on eks but it was not able to push metrics into Prometheus managed service.

EKS is provisioned in VPC.

**Error:**

> ts=2021-07-07T00:43:57.951Z caller=dedupe.go:112 component=remote
> level=warn remote_name=e595f3
> url=http://localhost:8005/workspaces/ws-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/api/v1/remote_write
> msg="Failed to send batch, retrying" err="server returned HTTP status
> 502 Bad Gateway: unable to proxy request - WebIdentityErr: failed to
> retrieve credentials"

**ingest policy:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "aps:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Trust relationship:**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/65ETDGGHD56WTRSDGF"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/65ETDGGHD56WTRSDGF:sub": "system:serviceaccount:test-eks-prometheus:amp-iamproxy-query-service-account"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

From "url=http://localhost:8005/workspaces/ws-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/api/v1/remote_write"it looks like you are trying to use sigv4 proxy.
Prometheus now supports sigv4 natively, I'd recommend this setup to remove one component to debug the problem through

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).